# Expl3 get everything before first subscript or apostrophe token

Tags: macros, expl3

I work with thousands of "symbols" that are either variables or constants. I want any variable `x` to be typeset as `\variable{x}`, and any constant `a` to be typeset as `\constant{a}`.

If the "symbol" is at least two characters long, then this symbol is a constant. If the symbol is one character long and in the range [a-h] or [A-H], then this symbol is a constant. Otherwise the symbol is a variable.

Assuming symbols are made of letters only, the following Expl3 code does this just right:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\constant}[1]{\mathsf{#1}}
\newcommand{\variable}[1]{#1}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \symbol { m } {
\str_case_x:nnTF { #1 } {
    {i}{}{j}{}{k}{}{r}{}{m}{}{n}{}{o}{}{p}{}{q}{}{r}{}{s}{}{t}{}{u}{}{v}{}{w}{}{x}{}{y}{}{z}{}
    {I}{}{J}{}{K}{}{R}{}{M}{}{N}{}{O}{}{P}{}{Q}{}{R}{}{S}{}{T}{}{U}{}{V}{}{W}{}{X}{}{Y}{}{Z}{}
  }{\variable{#1}}{\constant{#1}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\symbol{lorem}, \symbol{ipsum}, \symbol{a}, \symbol{x}$

\end{document}
```

However I would like some improvements, and I don't know how to do.

- If a symbol ends with one or several apostrophes (for example `x''`), these apostrophes need not be accounted in the rules above (that is, `x''` is a variable);
- If a symbol uses a subscript (for example `x_2`), then the subscript need not be accounted in the rules above (that is, `x_2` is a variable)

Currently I use an ugly adaptation of the code above where I added i' to z', i'' to z'' and i''' to z''' in the tests (and likewise for capital symbols). However I have no solution for subscripts. I think I could find one if I could make the following code work, but the string is not split as I expect it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \bla { m } {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \test {\c_math_subscript_token} {#1}
  \seq_use:Nn \test {,}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\bla{A_1}$

\end{document}
```

(This produces A with 1 as subscript, and not A followed by a comma followed by 1).

Just so that this makes sense to you, I apply this `\symbol` macro to a comma separated list, which allows me to write things like `a, x, y, z, b, a, g` instead of `\constant a, \variable x, \variable y, \variable z, \constant b, \constant a, \constant g`. I use thousands of symbols throughout my document and these shortcuts are really handy for me and make my LaTeX source code way more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This screams *regular expressions*!

- A run of two or more letters `[A-Za-z]{2,}` or
- one letter in `a-h` or `A-X`

should become `\constant{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\newcommand{\constant}[1]{\mathsf{#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\sym}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_pijcke_symbol_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([a-z]{2,}|[A-Ha-h]{1}) } { \c{constant}\cB\{\1\cE\} } \l_pijcke_symbol_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_pijcke_symbol_tl
 }
\tl_new:N \l_pijcke_symbol_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\sym{lorem}, \sym{ipsum}, \sym{a}, \sym{x}$

$\sym{a'}, \sym{B_1}, \sym{x''}, \sym{x_1}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my god! I didn't knew Expl3 had them! Is this a new feature? I'm not sure it is reasonable for me to ask my advisor to use some git version of l3kernel :p

Comment: @FabianPijcke It's still marked as “experimental”, but it is in every up-to-date distribution.

Comment: I just saw that l3regex addition in `\usepackage`. The official documentation says it was released two days ago :D Well if you say I can be confident in its availability, I'll just trust you :-) Thank your very much!

Comment: @FabianPijcke There was a new release two days ago, but `l3regex` has been available, essentially in the same form, for four years. You can also try `$\sym{abc+def+x+h}$`.

Comment: For those interested, I ended up using the following form, which allows me to use the `\variable` command, would it be something more than identity: `\regex_match:nnTF { (?i)(^[a-z]{2,}|[a-h]{1}) } { #1 } { \constant{#1} } { \variable{#1} }`